# ASP.Net Identity 2 RemovePassword Mocking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-identity

I want to give the avability for the administrator to change the password of a user.

I do it like this :

```
var result = await this.UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user.Id);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    result = await this.UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(user.Id, viewModel.MotDePasse);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { Id = viewModel.UserName });
    }
    else
    {
        viewModel.Errors = string.Join("<br />", result.Errors);
    }
}
else
{
    viewModel.Errors = string.Join("<br />", result.Errors);
}
```

When I run it, it works.
But when trying to unit test it, I get an error (in the result object) : "Name Connot be null".

In my unit test I have a TestInitialize like this :

```
_mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
var passwordStore = this._mockUserStore
                        .As<IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>>();
passwordStore.Setup(pm => pm.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
             .Returns(Task.FromResult<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationUser() { Id = "id", Nom = "Name1" }));

_userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(this._mockUserStore.Object);
```

How can I solve it ? Name on which object is null ?

Comment: Could you add a stack trace? The UserManager is possibly calling additional functions on your user store you haven't setup in your test. Or something completely different! ;-)

Comment: There is nothing interresting in the call stack (or I don't know to  get a deeper enought call stack) as soon as I don't catch any exception : just result.Errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to mock up UserValidator like this :

```
var mockUserValidator = new Mock<IIdentityValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
mockUserValidator.Setup(uv => uv.ValidateAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>()))
                 .Returns(Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(IdentityResult.Success));

this._userManager.UserValidator = mockUserValidator.Object;
```

And it works.

Answer (score 3):

That is the UserValidator probably rejecting the user update for not having a user name set.  You can probably just null out the UserValidator on the user manager

```
_userManager.UserValidator = null
```

Comment: Where you have 
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationUser() { Id = "id", Nom = "Name1" }));

change it to include UserName = "someusername", and don't set the UserValidator as shown above. I didn't include this an answer because it may not work!

Comment: Well... it doesn't work : the error is now "someusername" is already taken if UserValidator != null. if UserValidator == null, ArgumentNullException.

Comment: If null it out doesn't work, you can always implement an IUserValidator that is a NoopValidator

Comment: Thank you. I just need to mock up UserValidator AND setup ValidateAsync as shown in my answer.